# From an string that contains a symbol without knowing the encoding of that symbol, how can I show the complete string avoiding having errors?

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, character-encoding

I have many strings retrieved from a database that include some characters that I need to show, as for example € (I am using python 2.7). but the problem is that the following error appeared:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 33: invalid start byte
```

The string in this case is something like  `st = ‘ the price in  €’`  but it could be a different symbol (for now the error only appears in that case but in the future another character could give me that problem)

I managed that error using:

```
st = st.decode('utf8', errors='ignore')
```

The problem with that solution is that it removes the symbol €, but I want to show that symbol. I tried using `repr(st)` to find what encoding is and it gave me `‘\x80’`.

I want to find a way in which I can print that char € but without specifically search for that symbol (because it could be another) and manage to not have that error.

I don’t know if there is another way to see the problem, because my approach was to try  to find the encoding  of that char and try to converted in a normal string, but I found that the error also appeared trying to encode into ‘latin1’, ‘utf-8’ or ‘ascii’. Maybe my problem is that I don’t have any experience with encoding, I'm just a noob.

Comment: Why don't you know the encoding of that string? That's the fundamental problem here.

Comment: You *have* to know the encoding. You should absolutely not be investing effort in learning how to solve codec problems in Python 2.7. Python 3 does the right thing out of the box, and Python 2 has no real solutions, only conventions and rules of thumb.

Comment: No. I don't know the encoding of that string Because that string comes from another source and I don't have any way to know which encoding they are using.

Comment: You said it's coming from a database. Usually stuff stored in a database has a defined encoding. Are you just not aware of the encoding, or is it "random"? Most systems have ways to specify the used encoding, and those ways must be used. Only in truly exceptional circumstances should you be totally lost, and that's not a good place to be in.

Answer (score 0):

Try [chardet library](https://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#basic-usage)

This library can detect the encoding of strings. But it cannot guarantee to be 100% accurate because that is impossible, at least for now. You can read their docs for detailed explanation. Hopefully this solves your problem.